# Submit form only when an attachment is uploaded

Tags: jquery, forms, attachment

I'm currently looking for a way, to check if a user has uploaded files within a form. We have three upload inputs in our form - but the Form should only be submitted to the customer, if the user used the inputs to upload three files.

If the user clicks the submit-button, while there is no attachment uploaded, a Warning-Message should popup, to warn the user about the missing files.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if that's a "must be" condition, then you can simply show/hide the upload controls(html input type = file) one by one. i.e. when the user uploads one file, the other appears, after the second, the third one appears and **finally** after the third one is successfully uploaded, **the submit button is visible**. This way the user cannot submit form until all the files are uploaded. For safety, you can also add a server-side check before committing any user entries.

Comment: the thing is, as I commented on the advice before, that the form is generated by facile forms.

Comment: I've never used facile forms, but you must get some sort of confirmation once the files are successfully uploaded. Use it to change the value of some hidden element(like 1 to 2 to 3), and check against that value on click of the submit button. Also(not sure) but you should be disable/hide the elements using your own scripts, once the form is loaded/ready.

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped. But we decided, considering the age of the CMS and the plugin, not to work on this any further. It would take us several hours to get the whole thing done. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to check the contents of $_FILES global in the PHP before processing

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add this: We do not have the possibility to Use serverside technologies; We are using Facile Forms (2004/2006), a very antique Plugin for a very old Joomla version. Unfortuneately we don't have the possibility to update it.

Comment: Well, then you shouldn't have the PHP tag. I have removed for you.